# Map iterators traversal technique

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I was having problem declaring an iterator to traverse through a map and find values. I'm getting a error of "expected initializer before 'fibiter'".

```
map <int, int> fibHash;

int memoized_fib(int n)
{
    map <int, int> iterator fibiter = fibHash.find(n); //ERROR HERE

    if(fibiter != fibHash.end())
        return  *fibiter;

    int fib_val;
    if(n  <= 1)
        fib_val = 1;
    else
        fib_val = memoized_fib(n - 1) + memoized_fib(n - 2);

    fibHash[n] = fib_val;
    return fib_val;
}

int main()
[..]
```

Comment: Would you like to buy a pair of `:`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to use the scope resolution operator, `::`. The compiler thinks you declared a `map<int, int>` named `iterator`, and therefore gets mighty confused when it finds `fibiter`.

```
map<int, int>::iterator fibiter
```

is what you want

Answer (score 1):

`map <int, int> iterator` → `map <int, int>::iterator`

iterator is a typedef defined within the class "map".
You can look that up on the implementation of the standard library shipped with GCC 4.6.3 in `<bits/stl_map.h>` line 139, you have:

```
typedef typename _Rep_type::iterator               iterator;
```

As the typedef belongs to the definition of the class, you should add the ":" so that the compiler knows where to find it.